Appium Test started run on real android device or emulator but after a few second it close automatically. Please guide me how i can resolve this issue
I am automating tests on a real Android device using Appium. However, after launching the app, it crashes unexpectedly. Below are the details of my setup and the server logs I'm encountering.
Setup:

Platform: Android (Real Device)

Appium Version: 2.4.1

Programming Language: Java

OS: Windows 10


What I Tried:

Checked if the app crashes even when launched manually, and it works fine manually.

Tried updating the Appium server and resetting the device's hidden API policies as per the logs, but the issue persists.

Ensured the necessary capabilities are set correctly for the real device.


Issue:
After the app launches, Appium crashes and the session stops. The logs mention the app force-stopping, and I'm not sure how to resolve the hidden API policy issues mentioned.
Environment:

Android SDK Path: C:\Users\abubakar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Device: Real Android Device (OS Version: 12)

App: A custom family app (com.bamrec.family)


Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Please share appium session logs, it will be really hard for providing solutions without logs.
